# Explorer restarting after few seconds

Tags: windows, windows-8

First of all: I wish I would have stuck to 7 or 8.0, but it's 8.1 now ...

Not too old 8.1 installation (2 months maybe because the old one SNAFU'd). Worked OK until today. After login, desktop comes up (not metro, the "old" one) starts populating the taskbar etc, but after 2-3 seconds the screen flashes, and everything starts from the beginning. Looks just as if explorer.exe would be restarted each 2-3 seconds.
I could check the event log - but I can not, since you can not do anything, when your explorer permanently restarts :( Same happens when switching to the metro style desktop.

Any hints?

Update: Managed to get into safe mode (shift-restart). Explorer (partly) works. Event log shows indeed explorer.exe with application error (unknown module).
Each 1-4 Minutes in safe mode, an error pops up and the in event log, it lists MSVCR80.dll_unloaded as the faulty "module". Only hints I found where bound to iTunes - but I dont have this.

Update: Did a system restore (one week ago) to a point where the machine was working without problems -> still explorer.exe fails.

Comment: Sounds like you may have some malware or your install is corrupt.  [Possibly of interest to fix](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/msvcr80-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm)

Comment: Tried uninstalling Apple Update -> "you can not use windows installer in safe mode". GRR! Tried installing the Redist SP1 -> "You can not ...". GRRRRRR!

Comment: I agree with the others. Your installation is corrupt or some malware is to blame. Have you tried repairing your system files, using sfc /scannow ? It may work. More details about this command here: http://www.7tutorials.com/command-prompt-repair-missing-or-corrupt-files

Comment: @igrimpe You can try following these instructions to enable the MSI service in Safe Mode: http://wbracken.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/windows-enable-msi-service-in-safe-mode/